# What are those strange chainsaw scissors?

Tags: resident-evil-7

During a certain boss fight in *Resident Evil 7*, the opponent wields some strange chainsaw scissors.

> I am talking about the fight in the morgue with Jack Baker.

Is this weapon named in the game or is it a real-life tool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No they aren't a real tool (not like the one seen in the game at least).  As far as I know, there isn't an official name for them either.  Based off image searches (and my own experience), the weapon he uses is a chainsaw on the one blade of the "scissor" and some jagged scrap metal as the other blade.

Screenshot for reference:

[image: Jack Baker]

There are tools that are similar, but much smaller in size, such as [this one](http://twistedsifter.com/2010/05/alligator-lopper-chainsaw-scissors/) by Black & Decker which they call the Alligator Lopper:

[image: Chainsaw Scissors]

Comparing the two, Jack's doesn't appears to have a sleeve for the actual chainsaw blade as the actual tool does when one closes down on the blades.  Also, Jack's makes use of an actual chainsaw as one of the blades, while the real life one uses an electric motor.